# Can I save a plot from draw() funciton in R to combine with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, draw, complexheatmap

I have a heatmap generated with ComplexHeatmap, plotted using function draw(). I would like to add other panels (produced with ggplot) to the same figure, using ggpubr::ggarrange or cowplot::ggdraw, however I am not sure how to save heatmap plot as an object. Currenlty I am only able to plot heatmap directly to png or svg file.

```
hmap =  Heatmap(
  t(matr),
  col = col_fun,
  cluster_rows = F,
  cluster_columns = F,
  show_column_dend = F,
  show_column_names = F,
  row_names_side = "left",
  name = "Score", heatmap_legend_param = list(direction = "horizontal"),
  show_heatmap_legend = F,
  heatmap_height = unit(13, "cm"),
  top_annotation = ha_col_clusters,
  bottom_annotation = ha_col_clusters_enrichments
  )
lgd_score = Legend(col_fun = colorRamp2(c(-109, 0, 19), c("darkblue", "white", "darkorange")), title = "Score",
                   title_position = "topleft",
                   grid_height = unit(4, "mm"),
                   grid_width = unit(12, "mm"),
                   direction = "horizontal")
lgd_enrich = Legend(col_fun = colorRamp2(c(-5, 0, 15), c("darkblue", "white", "darkred")), 
                    title = "Enrichments",
                    title_position = "topleft",
                    grid_height = unit(4, "mm"),
                    grid_width = unit(12, "mm"),
                    direction = "horizontal")
svg("test.svg",width=12,height=6)
draw(hmap)
draw(lgd_score, x = unit(0.88, "npc"), y = unit(0.85, "npc"))
draw(lgd_enrich, x = unit(0.85, "npc"), y = unit(0.95, "npc"))
dev.off()
```